# Variable goes null in other function in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have two variables in my ViewController. In my `.h` I defined them like this.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myLongitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myLatitude;
```

In my `.m` I've synthesized them. like this.

```
@synthesize myLatitude = _myLatitude;
@synthesize myLongitude = _myLongitude;
```

Then in the function `updateLocation` I set these variables as following.

```
 _myLongitude = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",location.longitude];
   _myLatitude = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",location.latitude];
```

When I log these variables after that I've set them I get the correct values. But when I log the values in another function that is executed after the update Function, these variables goes `NULL`. Here are my logs.

```
        NSLog(@"longitude val is = %@", _myLongitude);
        NSLog(@"latitude val is = %@", _myLatitude);
```

Any help?

Comment: if you are using ARC, then you don't need to synthesize like `@synthesize myLatitude = _myLatitude;` it will be enough with `@synthesize myLatitude;` it could be null also because your location

Comment: Yes I use ARC. Can that be the problem?

Comment: check First your location.lon/lat are not null put NSLog befor convert it into String :)

Comment: Try once by using setter for those variables instead of using _myLongitude or _myLatitude.

Comment: @StefGeelen: even if you `@synthesized` it wont lead to error, your error source is something else.

Comment: Why are you even holding them as strings when they are better held in their raw `float` form?

Comment: @trojanfoe Because I need them as string to give it to the google API

Comment: Well convert them to strings just before passing them to the google API.

Comment: try converting like `NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", location.longitude];` without `alloc` and `init`

Answer (score 0):

> Then in the function updateLocation I set these variables as
>   following.

As clearly these are properties to the class, `updateLocation` is not the right place to `alloc`ate and `init`ialise them.

You should do it in, `viewDidLoad`, `init`, or as such method.

If you want to re-set the value then set it to `nil` and then put the new values instead of doing this.

Comment: So I just [[alloc]init] them in the ViewDidLoad and set them in the updateFunction ?

Comment: I've tried it, but no success. Keeps going Null. I set my variables in the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation function.

Comment: What about the object `location` it must be getting released resulting in `_myLatitude` and `_myLongitude` to null. Is it of type strong?

Comment: Yes they are of type strong.

Comment: Are you creating different instances of `location`? otherwise I cant see any problem at all :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25270/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-anoop-vaidya)